# Trying to get ID after slash in URL causing 404 Not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, http-status-code-404, slash

I am trying to get the ID of a URL after the last slash `/`. The URL looks like this:

`mysite.com/ID`

Right now, when i put ID after the slash, it gives me 404 Not found.

This code gets me the ID after slash, and full URL:

---

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo "$url<br />";

$fullurl = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $fullurl;
```

---

But the problem is that it shows 404 Not found, when i put ID after slash. Is it something i have to change in my `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to redirect your `http://site.com/id` URL to your `.php` file as

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The `id` now becomes available as `$_GET["id"]` in PHP. If you want to limit this to numbers use

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

If you want to pass `/any/path/any/page.php` to your PHP file use

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?uri=$1 [L]
```